# How to force view-rendering on the iPhone when it was previously not shown because of low memory?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, titanium

I am using Titanium and have a TableView with about 20 entries, each containing a ScrollableView that has some views itself.

When scrolling thru the table, the iOS hides some views within the ScrollableView because the memory gets low.

As soon as I touch the ScrollableView and move it slightly, the hidden view gets rendered again and is visible again.

Is there a way to force the view rendering on the screen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no working solution (yet) but I have a workaround that helped me out and did the job for my case:

Instead of creating a TableView with rows I created a ScrollView with single Views instead of TableViewRows. Using this workaround, the content of the ScrollableViews is always shown whenever they it appears on the screen.